# 503 response only on specific device for one call (iOS app)

Tags: ios, swift, api, http-status-code-503

I am having some issues with only one specific device.
One only one API call the device hangs and gets 503 back (I can see from Charles). All the other devices and simulator work fine without any issues.
On that device I tried to clean/install the app, update the iOS firmware, restart phone, tried both wifi and SIM. And also I have tried removing Charles and making sure on Wifi VPN or proxies are not enabled.

I have a common function for API calls, so some of the calls working come from the same function. just different path (same headers).

Is this an app/front end issue ? How can I proceed to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

Any error in 500+ range is a server side error. So general rule is that all 500+ errors should be investigated from server side *first*. Specifically

> 503 Service Unavailable server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.<...>

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503)

So my questions to server side would be:

- Who returned this error code to the client: it can be load balancer, or a server itself
- And why? Server or load balancer logs should have enough clues to figure it out.

On the client side, you can still do a few things:

1. Review the headers sent with 503 response. They may clue to what happened. For instance common pattern is to see if server did sent a `Retry-After` header (like the page above also suggests.
2. Since you said some requests succeed, compare the *actual IP* of the server in the response for success and failure (Charles shows it). It could be, that you have 2 or more nodes, and some of them are working properly, and some are not.
3. If you are dealing with some sort of cloud server (e.g. AWS), common case for 503 is some lack of permissions. [This](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/503-errors-on-developer-hub-cannot-access-site/488999) provides a nice example of such case. So check if the failure is about permissions.

   This failure is a bit tricky to debug even on the server, since
   server may not even log such attempt to access; in such case enable
   LB logs - they should point you in the right direction.

   If that's not possible, make sure you wipe all credentials from the device and
   try with account that definitely works. If your app is using
   keychain, make sure you clear it programmatically, since even
   uninstalling the app doesn't clean it up.
4. The combination of problems 2 and 3 is also quite common: permissions are not configured correctly on some nodes of the cluster, so depending on your luck, you may end up on a "bad" node. And since LBs and client cache server IPs, it may be that that particular device just ends up on a "bad" server most of the time.